# Can I use curl or curb to POST to a form that uses rails' Cross-site request forgery protection?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, curb

I have a simple rails webpage where a user enters in a few textfields and uploads a picture. Rails then stores the picture and updates the databases on the server. It works fine.

However, I also need a script on another computer to update the web page occasioanlly using the curl/curb libraries. When i try to do that, though, I get this error:

> ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken (ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken)

When I look closer, it seems that rails puts in a hidden field called "authenticity_token" whenever it creates a form:

> ```
> <form action="/headshots/single" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
> <input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="798b514826513c881613a0c18b52839489a12181" />
> . . .
> </form>
> ```

The curb script won't work because it doesn't have the "authenticity_token" thing. Is there any way around this? Maybe make another webpage that does the same thing, but just for my curb script?

Comment: The fact that you're using curl makes me guess you're coming from a php background. The good news is you will never have to use curl again.

Comment: Actually, I'm using curb which uses the curl libraries I believe. I haven't programmer PHP in years.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The hidden input is there to prevent [Cross-Site Request Forgery](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=csrf&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CDgQFjAA&url=http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery&ei=PF6eT8_rAeO3iQfI7IDWDg&usg=AFQjCNHTv-BNCKp3W0AVfOZ4jWQLWbdhgA&cad=rja).  You can't make a post to a rails action which is so protected without first getting the form and extracting the hidden `authenticity_token` parameter.  curl isn't clever enough to do this on its own.

You have two options:

1. turn off the CSRF protection by removing the call to `protect_from_forgery` from your controller(s).  Bad Idea.
2. run one request to get the form, use a quick-and-dirty regex to get the paremeter, say

   `/name="authenticity_token".*value="([^"]+)"/`

   and then run another request posting that value for `authenticity_token`. It's brittle and it might make people hate you but it will work.
3. Use something more sophisticated than `curl` to make the necessary request for the form and the successive submission.  [Mechanize](http://mechanize.rubyforge.org/) appears to be the de facto standard.

Comment: I'm not familiar with curb, but if this thing can do posts I assume it can do gets. Why not have it do a get and pull out the auth token and then do the post?

Comment: I was in agreement until you parsed that response with regex.

Answer (score 1):

How to submit a form with mechanize:

```
Mechanize.new.get('url_with_form').forms[0].tap{|f| f.field = 'value'}.submit
```